# Python vector field of ODE of three variables

Tags: python, numpy, vector, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a vector field of a ODE model with three variables. I would like to average the vectors along the third axis, and present the vector field together with the information of the standard deviation of their values. 
The ODE system is:

```
a  = 1.
b1 = 0.1
b2 = 0.11
c1 = 1.5
c2 = 1.6
d  = 0.75
def dudt(a,b1,b2,u,v1,v2):
    return a*u - b1*u*v1 - b2*u*v2
def dv1dt(d,c1,b1,u,v1):
    return -c1*v1 + d*b1*u*v1
def dv2dt(d,c2,b2,u,v2):
    return -c2*v2 + d*b2*u*v2
```

The function that I am currently using is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plotVF(mS=None, density= 20,color='k'):
    mB1 = np.linspace(0,1.1,int(density))
    mB2 = np.linspace(0,1.1,int(density))
    if mS==None:
        mS  = np.linspace(0,1.1,int(density))
        B1,B2,S = np.meshgrid(mB1,mB2,mS)
        average=True
    else:
        B1,B2 = np.meshgrid(mB1,mB2)
        S = mS
        average=False
    DB1 = dv1dt(d,c1,b1,S,B1)
    DB2 = dv2dt(d,c2,b2,S,B2)
    DS  = dudt(a,b1,b2,S,B1,B2)
    if average:
        print "Averaging"
        DB1std = np.std(DB1,axis=2)
        DB2std = np.std(DB2,axis=2)
        DB1 = np.mean(DB1,axis=2)
        DB2 = np.mean(DB2,axis=2)
        DS  = np.mean(DS,axis=2)
        vecstd = np.hypot(DB1std,DB2std)
        plt.imshow(vecstd)
        plt.colorbar()
        B1,B2 = np.meshgrid(mB1,mB2)
    M = (np.hypot(DB1, DB2, DS))
    M[ M == 0] = 1.
    DB1=DB1/M
    DB2=DB2/M
    DS=DS/M
    print B1.shape,B2.shape,DB1.shape,DB2.shape
    plt.quiver(B1, B2, DB1, DB2, pivot='mid', color=color)
    plt.xlim(0,1.1), plt.ylim(0,1.1)
    plt.grid('on')
    plt.show()
```

It gives me that the standard deviation along the third axis is zero, which does not make sense.
[image: Vector_Field]
Someone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please write some words about what you are trying to do? I have plotted vector fields before. But your code is too long to understand which portion exactly you are in trouble with.

Comment: @kanayamalakar I have added an image, the background colour of the vector field is suppose to be the standard deviation of the vectors for each point in the meshgrid, in respect to the third variable (on which I am doing the averaging)

Comment: It is not all zero. you have a lighter shade of blue at the top right corner than bottom left. So maybe just change the colorscale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost perfectly fine. There's only one problem: you're plotting the colormap with a vanilla call to `plt.imshow`.

As its name suggests, `imshow` is used for plotting images. As such, it by default doesn't expect coordinate inputs, just a single array containing the pixel data. This implies that a simple call to `imshow` will have axes limits corresponding to the number of pixels in your image -- in your case the dimensions of your 2d data arrays. If you take a look at the image directly created by `imshow`, you'll see that the limits go up to `x,y=20`. Later you set new limits according to your actual underlying mesh, truncating your plot to the first 2 data points.

The solution is to explicitly tell `plt.imshow()` where you want your plot to reside in coordinate space:

```
plt.imshow(vecstd, extent=[B1.min(),B1.max(),B2.min(),B2.max()], origin='lower')
```

The first keyword argument `extent` gives the `x` and `y` limits into which the data should be plotted. Note the important second keyword argument, `origin`. By default `imshow` plots things "upside down" in order to *not* plot actual images upside down. When you're using `imshow` to plot stuff defined with Cartesian coordinates, you have to tell it that the origin of the coordinate system should not be the *upper* left corner of the figure (as for images), bur rather the *lower* left corner (as for regular plots).